# Как настроить git для utf-8 bom, без изменения кодировки?

Tags: git, кодировка, интернационализация

Мне необходимо, чтобы файлы хранились в Git без перекодировки, и без изменений переносов строк.

В основном файлы в кодировке Utf-8 BOM, с комментариями на русском языке.

Меня вполне устраивает, что в начале файла отображается `<EF><BB><BF>` (BOM), но категорически не устраивает отображение текста на русском.

У меня есть настройка:

```
[i18n]
    filesEncoding = utf-8
[gui]
    encoding = utf-8
```

Для Git Gui это сработало, но для терминала - нет:
[image: Git Gui screen shot]
[image: Git terminal screen shot]

Какие настройки нужно сделать, чтобы в терминале отображались русские символы для diff?

Версия Git: 2.7.0.windows.1

UPDATE:
Попробовал вывести в файл, и оказалось, что все нормально с diff:

```
diff --git a/ConsoleApplication1/Program.cs b/ConsoleApplication1/Program.cs
index 84c414a..08959c7 100644
--- a/ConsoleApplication1/Program.cs
+++ b/ConsoleApplication1/Program.cs
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@ using System.Threading.Tasks;
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
     /// <summary>
-    /// По-русски.
+    /// По-русски. Еще по-русски.
     /// </summary>
     class Program
     {
```

Насколько я понял, что виноват less, пытаюсь исправить:

```
LESSCHARSET=UTF-8
```

Результат:
[image: Trying to fix less]

Как теперь поправить вывод в консоли?

Answer (score 3):

Ответ нашелся здесь:
https://mintty.github.io/

Для этого терминала можно установить настройки через Gui.
Для русского варианта подходят настройки:

Locale: UTF-8

Character set: ru_RU

[image: mintty settings for russian locale]